# Autoinsert right-to-left attributes Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, autocomplete, ide

I don't know all features of Android Studio, I have tried to search,but found nothing.
I wonder if it is possible to make Android Studio autoinsert attributes required for right-to-left support.
For example I have typed following line

```
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
```

Is it possible to make Android Studio insert `marginStart` attribute automatically ?

```
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
```

And vice-versa(for padding too).
This would save some time.

Maybe someone knows how to get such behavior, I will be grateful for any help. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, you can't do that. You have to write them yourself.

**The difference** between `layout_marginLeft` and `layout_marginStart` for example is that `layout_marginLeft` is executed for left to right languages like English, while `layout_marginStart' is only executed for right to left languages like Arabic.

So if you are going to add string translations to your app including arabic or any other right to left languages, you will need to write marginStart or marginEnd attributes... So anyway, if you didn't write `layout_marginStart` for example and your app doesn't support Arabic language or any other right to left languages, no error will occur to the user; it is just a warning that Android Studio tells you.

Definitely the same concept is applied to padding attributes. Hope that helps you.

**Edit:**

If you don't like to see Android Studio warning you these warnings, you can simply disable that by clicking on the yellow light bulb beside the yellow highlighted warning and selecting `Edit 'Using left/right instead of start/end attributes' inspection settings`, then uncheck it from the list.

But if you don't want to change the inspection settings, you can just add the following to your View that you don't want to use start/end attributes in it:

```
tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"
```

and add that to your parent layout that contains that View:

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I understand the difference and why this attribute was introduced. I just wondered if it is possible to save some time to do this insertion automatically.   
There will be no error, but warnings doesn't looks good for me, I check my code with lint,checkstyle.....
This is not big deal for me to type one more line, but it takes some time. 
Nevertheless thank you.

Comment: Check my updated answer if you want to get rid of these warnings. :)

Comment: I know this tools attribute, but nevertheless thank you for you help)